# How to get uniform line space for a mixed paragraph of texts and images

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I am using iText 7.2.1.

I am trying to add some small icons (drawn by code) in my text. I find if small icons are added into my text, it's hard to have uniform line space.

If all elements of a paragraph are texts, I can just set `SetFixedLeading()` then no matter how big the font sizes are, my lines have always the same height.

But when I add some small icons inside my paragraph, `SetFixedLeading()` no longer works.

What I want is like the "Line spacing" option in Microsoft Word. If I give it a fixed value, it treats embedding images and texts equally so I always get fixed line spacing.

The following is my code:

```
using iText.Kernel.Colors;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas;
using iText.Layout;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Xobject;
using iText.Layout.Element;
using iText.Kernel.Geom;
using iText.Kernel.Font;
using iText.IO.Font;

namespace iTextTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var writer = new PdfWriter("test.pdf");
            var pdf_doc = new PdfDocument(writer);
            var doc = new Document(pdf_doc, iText.Kernel.Geom.PageSize.DEFAULT, false);

            // Make a text of various sizes
            var mixed_paragraph = new Paragraph();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++)
            {
                var style = new Style();
                var size = (Math.Sin(i) + 2) * 10;
                style.SetFontSize((float)size);
                mixed_paragraph.Add(new Text("A").AddStyle(style));
            }            

            // Make a 20x20 icon
            var bounds = new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20);
            var xobj = new PdfFormXObject(bounds);
            var pdf_canvas = new PdfCanvas(xobj, pdf_doc);
            pdf_canvas.SetFillColor(ColorConstants.RED);
            pdf_canvas.Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20);
            pdf_canvas.Fill();
            var icon = new iText.Layout.Element.Image(xobj);
            mixed_paragraph.Add(icon);

            // Fixed leading
            mixed_paragraph.SetFixedLeading(10);

            doc.Add(mixed_paragraph);

            doc.Close();
            pdf_doc.Close();
            writer.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("OK");
        }
    }
}
```

This is what it looks like. The second line is right but the third line has more space than fixed leading 10.

[image]

I need this because, in my case, I need some small rectanglular icons that each contain two lines of integers and other info.

These icons have bigger height than my text (or else it's hard to read), but theoretically they can still fit because my text has enough spacing.

Unfortunately, my line spaces become uneven. Fixed leading seems not affecting non-text images, so lines with icons have wider line spaces.

I have been considering a workaround: add empty spaces in text and put icons at these fixed positions. It's still hard. I don't know how to get these positions.

Comment: Are you sure this is the full code? `var canvas = new Canvas...` is an orphaned variable. And running your code results in an `System.NullReferenceException` on `doc.Add(mixed_paragraph)`

Comment: @MetroSmurf Sorry I forgot to delete that line. I am using iText 7.2.1 and this code can run for me.

Comment: @MetroSmurf I have updated my code. Today I also find adding a negative top margin for my icon like this `icon.AddStyle(new Style().SetMarginTop(-20));`, can shrink the line height a little, but only a little.

Comment: Ran your code on win 10 w/ a net6.0 project and a standard .net 4.8 project. Both fail w/ null ref ex as described in my first comment.

Comment: @MetroSmurf That's weird. I am using VS Community 2022, iText 7.2.1/7.2.4 from NuGet, .Net 6.0, Target OS Windows version 7.0. Could you tell me where the null locates: `doc`, `mixed_paragraph`, or inside `Add()` method?